# Suppose $g$ is a symmetric bilinear form, is $\operatorname{rad} g = \operatorname{rad}(g+g^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that, when we have a field $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K) \ne 2$, that $\operatorname{rad} g = \operatorname{rad}(g+g^T)$?

I know that in such a field, a bilinear form can be written as the sum of a symmetric and an alternating bilinear form.

How do I use this fact to prove the given statement?

Thanks.

Comment: what is rad?...

Comment: @daw the radical

Comment: If $g$ is symmetric this is trivial since $g=g^T$, isn't it?

Comment: So rad$g$=rad$(2g$)?